# SQL Developer shortcut stopped working

Tags: 17.10

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

I had since I installed Ubuntu 17.10 a shortcut to SQL Developer.
This is how I created it:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
sudo touch sqldeveloper.desktop
sudo nano sqldeveloper.desktop
```

Data:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=SQL Developer
Icon=/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Exec=/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
```

This shortcut worked until last week, and the strange thing is that I did not change anything in my system that I can think of..

I still see the shortcut when I search for SQL Developer.

Now to start SQL Developer I have to do this in terminal:

```
/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh .
```

I've tried to add my user as the owner, and also give chmod +x:

```
sindre@selite:/usr/share/applications$ ll | grep sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sindre root   146 nov.   7 08:14 sqldeveloper.desktop
```